# Session lost after redirect post Login in cakePhp 2.4

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication, redirect

I am currently on cakePHP 2.4.5 and try to implement authorization. My AppController.php is:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'RequestHandler',

        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'themeroles',
                'action' => 'add'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            )
        )   
    );

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        $auth = CakeSession::read('Auth');
        if (isset($auth['User'])){ 
            $loggedInUser = $auth['User']['username'];
            $loggedInRole = $auth['User']['role'];
            // Admin can access every action
            if (isset($loggedInRole) && $loggedInRole === 'admin') {
                return true;
            }
            if (isset($loggedInUser) &&!empty($user) && $loggedInUser === $user) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        CakeSession::write('redirectURL', Router::reverse($this->request, true));
        // Default deny
        return false;
    }

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
    }

}
```

My UsersController has:

```
public function beforeFilter() {

    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add', 'logout');
}

public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

but after the redirect, it seems the session gets killed. I automatically get redirected to the login page.

I found as a possible solution to set in the core.php:

```
Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
Configure::write('Security.cookie', 'cakephpfdebackend');
Configure::write('Session.cookieTimeout', 0);
Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', false);
Configure::write('Session.cookie_secure',false);
Configure::write('Session.referer_check' ,false);
Configure::write('Session.defaults', 'php');
```

but that does not help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on your `isAuthorized()` function. Before writing a new session every time you try to login, it finds that `isset($auth['User'])` is set but empty. Thus both `if` don't run at all. As a result it returns false.

So, try:

```
if (!empty($auth['User'])){
```